# defineProperty on nested class object

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototype

Let's say we have this class:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    this.oneProp = 'one prop';
    this.myProps = {
        prop1: 'my prop1',
        prop2: 'my prop2'
    };
});
```

How can I configure a getter / setter on **myProps.prop1** using `Object.defineProperty` so that when I change `myProps.prop1`, the value of `myProps.prop2` is set to, for example, `'_'+prop1`?

I found an easy way to define a getter / setter on `oneProp` using:

```
Object.defineProperty(MyClass.prototype, 'oneProp', {
    ...
});
```

But I can't figure out how to do the same on `myProps.prop1`.

Thanks

Comment: You can't put properties of instance properties on the prototype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write the getter directly in the object literal.

```js
var MyClass = function() {
    this.oneProp = 'one prop';
    this.myProps = {
        prop1: 'my prop1',
        get prop2() { return '_' + this.prop1; },
        set prop2(v) { this.prop1 = v; }
    };
}

var x = new MyClass;
document.write(x.myProps.prop2 + '<br>');
x.myProps.prop2 = 42;
document.write(x.myProps.prop2 + '<br>');
```